# Back cursor to beginning of textbox after hit on enter to avoid line break and avoid white-space

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, whitespace

I have two related problems, need your help to figure out.

in my program I write the any phrase in textBox1, then I hit the enter button on my keyboard and see this text in the textBox2.

but when I hit the enter to show my phrase in textBox2, cursor in textBox1 goes to the next line and creates line break

But after hit enter and cleaning, I want return cursor to the beginning of textBox1.

I tried it this way:

```
textBox1.Focus();
textBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

and this, but doesn't works for me:

```
textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
```

besides that I just want to return the cursor to the beginning,  this line break violates the order in a text document, because I write this lines to the text document. line by line after each hit on enter.

For example, if with button use I have this order in result:

```
phrase1   
phrase2
phrase3
...
```

with Enter I got this:

```
phrase1 

phrase2

phrase3
```

I think that the solution  of this problem can't  solve following one, so as they are related, it would be good to solve this one too, because I have no idea, how to do it.

also I have to avoid the white-space which can be left at the end of the line, before I hit the enter. It is also violates the order in my text document. I don't want the phrase or word with white-space at the end:

```
phrase1< without white-space 
phrase2 < with unwanted white-space at the end 
...
```

here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XXX_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ActiveControl = textBox1;
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                textBox2.AppendText(textBox1.Text + "\n");
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Solution with `String.TrimEnd()` function and `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace XXX_TEST
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ActiveControl = textBox1;
            }

            private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                     textBox2.AppendText(textBox1.Text.TrimEnd() + "\n");
                     textBox1.Text = "";
                     e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                }

                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? Currently I don't understand at all what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Visual Vincent hello, done, hope now better

Comment: So you basically want to clear `TextBox1` every time the user hits Enter? You say the caret doesn't go back to the beginning, which I don't understand since when the TextBox have no text in it the caret will be in the beginning.

Comment: Hold on, I think I see your problem. Let me write an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the reason for your first two problems. When the `KeyDown` event runs you check for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and if it was pressed you do your actions and clear `textBox1`. However, you still have not stopped the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key message from being passed onto the `TextBox`.

The fix is to set the [**`e.SuppressKeyPress` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` which will cause the key press to not be passed to the `TextBox`, thus it won't add another new line in it.

As for your third request about removing any trailing spaces you just have to utilize the [**`String.TrimEnd()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox2.AppendText(textBox1.Text.TrimEnd() + "\n"); //TrimEnd() removes trailing white-space characters.
        textBox1.Text = "";
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true; //Do not pass the Enter key press onto the TextBox.
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is solved, big support. so all I need is `textBox2.AppendText(textBox1.Text.TrimEnd() + "\n");
                textBox1.Text = "";
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Comment: @MoIC : Yes that's all you need (if it worked, that is). :)

Comment: yes works, I have added above solution with your help with same example

Comment: @MoIC : Technically not necessary, as I already wrote it in an answer :). Good luck with your project!